# Store results of SQL Server query for pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pagination

In my database I have a table with a rather large data set that users can perform searches on. So for the following table structure for the `Person` table that contains about 250,000 records:

```
firstName|lastName|age
---------|--------|---
John     | Doe    |25
---------|--------|---
John     | Sams   |15
---------|--------|---
```

the users would be able to perform a query that can return about 500 or so results. What I would like to do is allow the user see his search results 50 at a time using pagination. I've figured out the client side pagination stuff, but I need somewhere to store the query results so that the pagination uses the results from his unique query and not from a `SELECT *`  statement.

Can anyone provide some guidance on the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Side note: I've been trying to use temp tables to do this by using the `SELECT INTO` statements, but I think that might cause some problems if, say, User A performs a search and his results are stored in the temp table then User B performs a search shortly after and User A's search results are overwritten.

Comment: What differs between searches?

Comment: The actual query itself. User A might search for `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age BETWEEN 10 AND 20` and User B might search for `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age = 25`. For each query, I want its results to be stored in a cache of some sort and the pagination scripts on the client side to page through the results stored in the respective caches and not run the SQL query again.

Think of the experience Google provides when you're doing a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is great for pagination, and may be helpful depending on what parameters change between searches, for example if searches were just for different firstName values you could use:

```
;WITH search AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY firstName ORDER BY lastName) AS RN_firstName
                 FROM YourTable)
SELECT *
FROM search 
WHERE RN BETWEEN 51 AND 100
  AND firstName = 'John'
```

You could add additional `ROW_NUMBER()` lines, altering the `PARTITION BY` clause based on which fields are being searched.

Comment: A colleague of mine pointed out that my "ideal" approach would turn out to be far too memory intensive and that using default SQL paging was the way to go. This seems like a clean enough solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, for us, the best way to manage this is to create a complete new table, with a unique name. Then, when you're done, you can schedule the table for deletion.

The table, if practical, simply contains an index id (a simple sequenece: 1,2,3,4,5) and the primary key to the table(s) that are part of the query. Not the entire result set.

Your pagination logic then does something like:

```
SELECT p.* FROM temp_1234 t, primary_table p 
WHERE t.pkey = p.primary_key 
  AND t.serial_id between 51 and 100
```

The serial id is your paging index.

So, you end up with something like (note, I'm not a SQL Server guy, so pardon):

```
CREATE TABLE temp_1234 (
    serial_id serial,
    pkey number
);

INSERT INTO temp_1234
  SELECT 0, primary_key FROM primary_table WHERE <criteria> ORDER BY <sort>;

CREATE INDEX i_temp_1234 ON temp_1234(serial_id); // I think sql already does this for you
```

If you can delay the index, it's faster than creating it first, but it's a marginal improvement most likely.

Also, create a tracking table where you insert the table name, and the date. You can use this with a reaper process later (late at night) to DROP the days tables (those more than, say, X hours old).

Full table operations are much cheaper than inserting and deleting rows in to an individual table:

```
INSERT INTO page_table SELECT 'temp_1234', <sequence>, primary_key...

DELETE FROM page_table WHERE page_id = 'temp_1234';
```

That's just awful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you really need to do this.  You're adding significant complexity, so go & measure whether the queries and pagination really hurts or you just "feel like you should".  The pagination can be handled with ROW_NUMBER() quite easily.

Assuming you go ahead, once you've got your query, clearly you need to build a cache so first you need to identify what the key is.  It will be the SQL statement or operation identifier (name of stored procedure perhaps) and the criteria used.  If you don't want to share between users then the user name or some kind of session ID too.

Now when you do a query, you first look up in this table with all the key data then either

a) Can't find it so you run the query and add to the cache, storing the criteria/keys and the data or PK of the data depending on if you want a snapshot or real time.  Bear in mind that "real time" isn't really because other users could be changing data under you.

b) Find it, so remove the results (or join the PK to the underlying tables) and return the results.

Of course now you need a background process to go and clean up the cache when it's been hanging around too long.

Like I said - you should really make sure you need to do this before you embark on it.  In the example you give I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight. I really didn't think it would have been that complicated.